# tether-shepherd not compatible with angular version 1.7.0

Tags: angularjs, tether, angular-sanitizer

Earlier I was using angular version 1.5 and angular sanitize version  1.5. But now I have updated my dependency from version 1.5 to 1.7 for both angular and angular sanitize and in the updated version Shepard cards are not working.
So anybody have any idea if there is any compatibility issue between tether-shepherd 1.8.1  and angular 1.7.

Not working means Shepard card not coming up on page when it is supposed to be.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you getting any error messages?  "Not working" doesn't really explain much....

Comment: Thats the thing, I am getting no error